# ComboBox Swing Empty despite added data

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have create comboBox in my panel, and I am setting the data like that:

```
    public void buildProductList(){
    for (Flower flower:this.controller.getComboModel()
         ) {
        this.productSelect.addItem(flower);
    }
}
```

Where:

```
public Flower[] getComboModel(){
 Flower[] flowers = {new Rose("Rose", 5f),new Sunflower("Sun",5f)};
 return flowers;
}
```

As I can see from the debugger,

```
this.productSelect.selectedItemReminder = {Rose@1658}...
```

Which, as I understand, means that I've set the options for the combobox. However, when I click on the box, it displays nothing (empty boxes and there is no placeholder). What am I missing?

**Update**

I initalize my ComboBox like this:

```
private JComboBox<Flower> productSelect = new JComboBox<Flower>();;
```

**UPDATE 2**

Since many of you have asked, here is better representation of the situation:

I've added `ComboBox` in Intellij GUI Designer and set its field name to `productSelect`:

[image]

Then, I coded my panel:

[image]

And here is the output:

[image]

When I click the `ComboBox` it displays nothing, and disapears within miliseconds.

I hope those details help.

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* - A runnable example which demonstrates your problem. The only conclusion I can draw is the combobox you updating is not the one which is displayed on the screen

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: please add some code so that we can help

Comment: @shimbushambu, I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do, is remove to change the following:

```
private JComboBox<Flower> productSelect = new JComboBox<Flower>();
```

into:

```
private JComboBox<Flower> productSelect;
```